How To Move Content From One Field To Another Field In Same Content Type For All Nodes?
I started a Drupal site about antique collecting years ago and made the mistake of creating a field “Category” which lists all of the antique categories instead of using Taxonomies. A user would choose a single Category that best fits their item. Now I want to do things like use Views and Contextual Filters (Taxonomy term ID from URL) to show Related Content after someone views a page.
I now need to move the data from the Category field (Category, field_general_item_category  List (text)) into a new Taxonomy field (Entity reference Reference type: Taxonomy term Vocabulary: Appraisal Categories) for each node.
So, if a node has a category named, “Figurines” I need to move that data into the Taxonomy field In the same node. I can’t figure out how to do this. I’ve looked at VBO (Views Bulk Operations), but don’t exactly know what to do PHP-wise.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I would do this in a hook_update_N() implementation.

Take a database dump.

Set up your taxonomy, and ensure that you have created a taxonomy term for each label of the allowed values list.

Create a custom module.

Enable it.

Create the file [MODULE].install.

In that file, implement [MODULE]_update_10000():
/**
 * Convert field_general_item_category on nodes to Appraisal Category terms.
 *
 * Implements hook_update_N().
 */
function [MODULE]_update_10000() {
   // Get the entity query for nodes.
  $query = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getQuery('node');
  // Get the Node IDs of any nodes that have a value for field_general_item_category.
  $nids = $query->exists('field_general_item_category')
    ->execute();

  // Only do something if node IDs were found.
  if (!empty($nids)) {
    // Prepare to load nodes and terms.
    $node_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
    $term_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term');

    // This will be populated on the first iteration of the loop.
    $allowed_values = NULL;

    // Loop through the found node IDs.
    foreach ($nids as $nid) {
      // Load the node.
      $node = $node_storage->load($nid);
      // Check if $allowed_values has been initalized.
      if (is_null($allowed_values)) {
        // Load the allowed values map.
        $allowed_values = $node->getFieldDefinition('field_general_item_category')
          ->getFieldStorageDefinition()
          ->getSetting('allowed_values');
      }
      // Get the value of the list field.
      $value = $node->get('field_general_item_category')->value;
      // Determine if a label mapping exists.
      if (isset($allowed_values[$value]) && $label = $allowed_values[$value]) {
        // Attempt to load a matching term for the label.
        if ($term = $term_storage->loadbyProperties(['name' => $label])) {
          // A term was found, so it is set as a value on the term reference field.
          $node->set('field_appraisal_categories', $term->id()
            ->save();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Note that I arbitrarily used the field name field_appraisal_categories as you did not provide the actual field name, so you'll need to update my code to use the field name of the 'appraisal category' term reference field you have added the node. You'll also need to replace [MODULE] with the machine name of your module.

Run drush updb to run your code.


If something fails, you can increase the value in the function name by one (eg 10000 to 10001) then re-run drush updb.
